# Is there a way to pre-order a pack of 5 CD/DVDs for the upcoming Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, cd

Sure, I could just wait and download it, but I really want to get my hands on it right away. Besides, I don't have a fast connection where i'm currenly living so it could take some time to download. Thanks for your attention.
By the way, I know there's a lauching party on a city nearby, but I really don't think I could make it on time >.<

Answer (score 1):

You can purchase CDs and DVDs in packs of 5, 20, 100 or 200 from the Canonical Store, but they haven't mentioned anything about pre-order of 11.10 discs. Maybe it'll show up there once 11.10 is released. More info here - [Canonical Shop](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17)

[The Linux Store](http://www.thelinuxstore.org/) has an Ubuntu section, where you can pre-order Ubuntu 11.10 discs as well. Here is the [Ubuntu Section at The Linux Store](http://www.thelinuxstore.org/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=41_47&zenid=9f55b307578e198d2af1c2f67798c31b)

Comment: anyway..that's the only option for u, since cannonical has stopped the free cd offer they have been running since 2 year... :(